# Ethers.js: How can I limit the amount of results I get when using queryFilter?

Tags: ethers.js, filters

I'm aware I can limit the results by utilizing fromBlock[,toBlock]. But I have no way of knowing which blocks held the event. Is there any way to just get the last n results without referencing blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely depends on the RPC provider. Providers like Alchemy and Infura doesn't offer this feature, you'll need to go by blockhash/block number. However, [Moralis](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#code) seem to offer a filter by date feature. [Covalent](https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#/0/Get%20log%20events%20by%20contract%20address/USD/1) also seems to have some sort of pagination feature, you could take a look at them. But in general, it's not a standard feature of RPC providers.

Comment: I am using Alchemy and I can say that this is wrong. I am using `queryFilter` too and I'm getting the results I want. One thing you can do, is query the last block number let's call it `lastBlock` and pass it to the query `fromBlock: lastBlock - n` and `toBlock: lastBlock`

Comment: I landed here because I had the same issue, turned out the parameters I was passing were wrong, so maybe you want to check that again

Comment: The original question was about getting the last n events (irrespective of which block), not events in the last n blocks.